# VBA Access to Word Mail Merge

Tags: ms-access, ms-word

I am running a sub routine in MS Access 2010 that runs a mail merge in Word.  I have two instances - one that sends the document to a printer and the second creates PDF files.  When I first run the routine it works perfect.  If I try to run it a second time with different data selected it stops at the ActiveDocument.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters line.  If I reset the code prior to executing the routine it will run fine.  I'm not sure if it is releasing all the objects or other parameters correctly after running through the routine.  I get Run Time 462  The remote machine does not exist or is unavailable.

Comment: Pleas post your code so that we can see what is happening.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more readable. With code blocks for instance.